# Use Spring batch or just a scheduling task with Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I want to consume a Rest api to populate a static list in my app, I want the list to be populated both when my app starts and at a particular time of day. Traceability is also required.

Is it better to create a job using Spring batch or just create a schedule job with Spring ?

Please share your thoughts with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would Spring Batch help with this? It is for processing large volumes of data, it isn't a scheduler.

Comment: @M. Deinum  I asked this question because I had the same thought as you when they told me to create a job with spring batch.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it better to create a job using Spring batch or just create a schedule job with Spring ?

Spring Batch provides APIs to launch jobs, but it does not provide any feature for scheduling. So you can use both: the business logic can be implemented as a Spring Batch job, and the scheduling logic of that job can be done with Spring Framework's scheduling capabilities (through the `@Scheduled` annotation for instance). Here is an example:

```
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduledJobConfig {
    
   @Autowired
   private Job job;

   @Autowired
   private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

   @Scheduled(cron = "* 10 * * * *")
   public void runJob() {
      JobParameters parameters = new JobParameters();
      // add parameters as needed
      this.jobLauncher.run(this.job, parameters);
   }

}
```

Comment: If the job that we are running is taking long? Will it affect the cron job?

Comment: It depends on the TaskExecutor you set on the job launcher. If it is a synchronous executor, there will be one thread running all jobs and if that thread is busy running the previous schedule, the launcher will fail on the next schedule. If the executor is asynchronous (ie a thread pool), then each job will be run in a different thread and won't impact other scheduled runs.