# Set scheduling for Job in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm working on a Forecasting method to use in a Java Spring project.

My boss requested me to launch this *generateForecast()* method in a batch, using Spring Batch.

He wants me to use Spring Batch to enable a scheduling, since my backend should be run every 24 hours. He explained to me that i could insert this method in a Job, and i could set the scheduling in the Spring Batch properties.

However, i'm noticing a lack of information on the internet about this. The only way i found to schedule a Job is by using the tag @Scheduling, with a cron expression inside.

Any help? Also, if you have advice to use Spring Batch's Job in the best way, i would be glad!

Answer (score 1):

Spring Batch provides APIs to launch jobs, but it does not provide any feature for scheduling. The scheduling logic can be done with Spring Framework's scheduling capabilities (through the `@Scheduled` annotation for instance) or with an a scheduling library like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org).

Comment: Thank you very much. Thing is, my project leader told me to use Spring Batch EXACTLY for Scheduling. So, since that's the main goal i'm aiming for, i could simply use the @Scheduled annotation and not use Spring Batch, right? That's something i must ask

Comment: Yes, just scheduling the method with Spring Framework's `@Scheduled` should work. Now, depending on the code of `generateForecast()`, it could be wrapped in a Spring Batch job (to benefit from Spring Batch features). This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75814083/5019386.